# Long press gesture on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to recreate the behaviour in Instagram app. When a user has multiple Instagram accounts, the settings tab becomes the current users profile picture. (attached)[image: Settings icon becomes profile picture]

When a user long presses on the settings tab item it produces a pop up view to change accounts. Its important to specify that this long press gesture is triggered even if I am not on the settings tab. This makes it easy to switch accounts from anywhere in the app. Here is the attached photo

[image: change account view]

I would like to produce the same behaviour for the tab bar item. I have already created the swapping account transition. I just dont know how to add a gesture recognizer to a bar button item, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried the Long-Press gesture element? https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/detecting-long-press-gestures-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: How can you add a long press gesture element programmatically? @JuanCurti